# Convert lots of text in one cell into numeric values

Tags: excel, numeric, categorical

I was given a dataset with a column containing the ways that a population paid for a specific service over the course of 4+ encounters. In this column one cell contains ~4 ways a patient paid (e.g., Credit Card, Check, etc.) in a list format. I want to calculate the mode of this column (to get the method each person paid utilized most often) and to do this I want to convert the text to numeric codes and calculate the mode based on this.

I have found many ways to do this online for one piece of text in one cell, but how do I convert multiple lines of text into lots of numbers in Excel?

The data is presented like this:

| Customer | Payment form - last 4 visits |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Credit Card, Check, Credit Card, Credit Card |
| 2 | Apple Pay, PayPal, Credit Card, Apple Pay |
| 3 | PayPal, PayPal, PayPal, PayPal |
| 4 | Venmo, PayPal, Venmo, Venmo |

I want to be able to convert the data into the following:

| Customer | Payment form - last 4 visits |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1, 2, 1, 1 |
| 2 | 3, 4, 1, 3 |
| 3 | 4, 4, 4, 4 |
| 4 | 5, 4, 5, 5 |

So I can ultimately get the following table:

| Customer | Most Frequent Payment Form |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 5 |

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps a small copiable example dataset, five rows' worth or so, together with expected result, would be useful.

Comment: *"how do I convert multiple lines of text into lots of numbers in Excel?"* You can do that using a VBA macro, power query, and, if you have office 365, you can probably do it with formulas.

Comment: @JosWoolley Thanks for the feedback, I have included a table I hope would be helpful!

Comment: Thanks. So a given customer only every has one row's worth of data?

Comment: @JosWoolley Yes that's correct.

Comment: What's your Excel version?

Comment: It's the most updated version I believe

Answer (score 0):

For breaking the lists into individual elements, one can use formulae, but easier are:
a) Data | Text to Columns | Delimiter | choose comma
or one I found very recently:
b) Paste the data (without the header) into Notepad++. Then copy it from Notepad++ and paste into Excel!
Beyond that, it sounds as though you know how to do the rest already.

Comment: Thank you so much! I should mention that there are 100k+ rows. Will these strategies work for that many?

Comment: a) certainly will cope with large volume. I have never tried b) on that volume.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what the result should be if more than one Payment Form share the modal value, so I assume that is not possible.

For a Payment Form in `B2`:

`=LET(ζ,TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(B2,",")),INDEX(ζ,MODE(MATCH(ζ,ζ,0))))`